# where is a symfony bundle's base root saved?

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have a working symfony2 bundle on my computer (in the wamp/www/symfony folder).
when I try to move it to a different computer, I get an error trying to get to it saying that filesystem.php can't find my index.php.twig - 
the thing is it's looking for it in the original path (the one in the 1st computer). 
I was looking all over for where it gets this path from and I find only relative paths (as I would expect). does anyone know where can I find the path to be changed?

(2ndly, is there a way to point to and run a project from a different location - say, my svn directory?)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a cahe issue. Try clearing it with `php app/console cache:clear`

About your second question, you can serve a Symfony2 application from any path that your web server can access